# How to get the current repetition count of the test in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

In JUnit 5, a method can be annotated with `@RepeatedTest(`**`n`**`)` so that it is run **`n`** times. How can I display the current number of repetition in that test method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide a parameter of type `RepetitionInfo` in your test method, a resolver will automatically provide an instance of that:

```java
@RepeatedTest(5)
void repeat(RepetitionInfo repetitionInfo) { // Automatically injected
    System.out.println(repetitionInfo.getCurrentRepetition());
    System.out.println(repetitionInfo.getTotalRepetitions());
}
```

As you can see, you can access the current repetition count as well as the total repetitions (n) by the provided parameter.

Comment: And read the User-Guide for more details https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-repeated-tests